# Conway's Game of Life Rules Java

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I am making the Conway's Game of Life like almost every other beginner. The main problem I have is I have no clue how to implement the rules for the game, which are :a dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes alive, a live cell with exactly one live neighbor becomes dead, and a live cell with more than three live neighbors becomes dead. I've never manipulated a matrix before so I do not have any idea where to start. The class I'm in does not allow us to use non-static methods yet, and also we cannot use the java libraries. This is currently what I have:

```
public class Life {
public static boolean[][] origin(int a) {
    boolean[][] randomMatrix = new boolean [a][a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
        randomMatrix[i][j] = StdRandom.bernoulli();
        }
    }
    return randomMatrix;
    }
public static void print(boolean[][] a) {
    int N = a.length;
    StdOut.println(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (a[i][j]) StdOut.print("1 ");
            else         StdOut.print("0 ");
        }
        StdOut.println();
    }
} 
public static void show(boolean[][] a, boolean which) {
    int N = a.length;
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, N-1);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, N-1);
    double r = .5;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == which) {
                StdDraw.filledSquare(j, N-i-1, r);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    boolean[][] b = origin(a);
    int gens = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < gens; i++) {
        System.out.println("Generation " + i + ":");
        print(b);
        show(b, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm receiving right now is what I need for the initial generation of the game. I think I need a new array to store the new generations, and maybe some if and else statements to check if the cells are alive or dead. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [classmate of yours?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585278/conways-game-of-life-bug)

Answer (score -1):

***HINTS***
Recently I completed this example. So the right structure is:

1. Required 2 dimension arrays ("current" & "next")
2. Initialize "current" with random values
3. print "current"
4. Copy & Calculate each cell of the next generation in array "next"
5. After calculation, update the "current" array. Use function to update each cell
6. Set "current" with "next" generation values
7. Print "current" and go to step 4